# UI component or design pattern for juxtaposition of images for comparison

Tags: design-patterns, terminology, image, component, image-slider

This was a design concept/pattern that I first saw in use for an interactive on a website to show the before and after images of a natural disaster event.

Since then I have seen it pop up in a couple of different places, but mostly used to show before/after images in an interactive side-by-side comparison. Below is an example that I saw on a website showing the transformation of one type of image into another.

[image]

Would this UI component be classified as a slider, an image interaction or something else?

This is the only implementation of the design pattern that I have seen (with the slider in the middle of the overlaid images) but if there are sightings of alternate designs please also add them to the answers.

Comment: "Image Comparison Slider" seems to be an accepted name though there isn't any official name that I can find in any design system. Refer: https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/js-image-comparison-sliders/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest : Image Comparison Slider

This an example I have seen months ago on Esri's website:

- https://storymaps.esri.com/stories/diabetes/

And another website that references the term:

- http://thenewcode.com/819/A-Before-And-After-Image-Comparison-Slide-Control-in-HTML5

Comment: Please add an explanation preferably supported by some sources.